# General formula to stay inside the boundaries?

Tags: inequality

I have the following inequality:

x<y<z.

I want to write a general formula that is going to help me to always stay between x and z. Is there any formula that includes all variables x,y & z for that?

For example, something like the following:

a = z*x/y.

No matter what the x,y,z values, it always give a value between the boundries.

3<4<5

a=15/4, a is between x and z.

or

1<49<50

a=50/49, a is between x and z.

I guess this holds when we have the nonnegativity constraint. But in our problem x<y<z is the only constraint.

Comment: $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is always between $a$ and $b$, so is $\sqrt{ab}$.

Comment: Would $\frac {x+z} 2$ do the trick?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that y must be in the formula. Otherwise both are correct.

Comment: How about $\frac{x+z}{2}\times \frac{y}{y} $?

Comment: How about $\frac{x+y+z}{3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $x<\frac{x+y}{2}<y<z$ and $x<y<\frac{y+z}{2}<z$ hence $x<\frac{\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{y+z}{2}}{2}<z$.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!